# QToolButton visual behavior inside a QFrame/QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qt4.8

I have realised that a **QToolButton** works differently when added to a **QToolBar** compared to how it behaves when added to a layout of a QFrame/QWidget.

What style option do I need to set on the **QToolButton**, so it behaves inside a **QFrame** exactly the same way as it would (visually) inside a **QToolBar**?

My current platform is OS X, this behavioral difference is same on both Qt 4.8 and 5.1 (upon my tests).

Thank you

Example:

[image: QToolButton behavior difference]

Code used to create the below scenario:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc,argv);

  QMainWindow* window    = new QMainWindow();
  QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget();
  QVBoxLayout* layout    = new QVBoxLayout();

  centralWidget->setLayout(layout);
  window->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
  window->setWindowTitle("QToolButton inside QToolBar vs QFrame/QWidget");

  layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
  layout->setSpacing(30);

  QToolBar* toolBar = new QToolBar();
  toolBar->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
  layout->addWidget(toolBar);

  QToolButton* button_1 = new QToolButton();
  button_1->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
  button_1->setIcon(QPixmap(":/icons/icons/1.png"));
  button_1->setIconSize(QSize(32, 32));
  button_1->setText("Button 1");
  toolBar->addWidget(button_1);

  QToolButton* button_2 = new QToolButton();
  button_2->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
  button_2->setIcon(QPixmap(":/icons/icons/2.png"));
  button_2->setIconSize(QSize(32, 32));
  button_2->setText("Button 2");
  toolBar->addWidget(button_2);

  QToolButton* button_3 = new QToolButton();
  button_3->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
  button_3->setIcon(QPixmap(":/icons/icons/3.png"));
  button_3->setIconSize(QSize(32, 32));
  button_3->setText("Button 3");
  // toolBar->addWidget(button_3);

  QToolButton* button_4 = new QToolButton();
  button_4->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
  button_4->setIcon(QPixmap(":/icons/icons/4.png"));
  button_4->setIconSize(QSize(32, 32));
  button_4->setText("Button 4");
  // toolBar->addWidget(button_4);

  QFrame* frame     = new QFrame();
  frame->setStyleSheet("QFrame { background: #ff0; }");
  layout->addWidget(frame);

  QHBoxLayout* frame_layout = new QHBoxLayout();
  frame_layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
  frame_layout->setSpacing(0);
  frame->setLayout(frame_layout);

  frame_layout->addWidget(button_4);
  frame_layout->addWidget(button_3);
  // button_4->animateClick(10000);
  frame_layout->addStretch();

  window->show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: What is the difference you have noticed? Which version of Qt are you using? Can you include a piece of code?

Comment: @mhcuervo, please see the added image and explanations. I didn't put any code as it consists of creating 4 buttons, a toolbar and a frame and adding them. But I will put it as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is desired behavior and is coherent with visual behavior of other OS X applications, as far as I can tell. You may want to rethink whether what you're after is advisable. If you come up with a good reason, then I can look further into it.

Comment: Hello @KubaOber, thank you for your answer. What I'm working on is a custom QFrame, to function and to be used just like a QToolBar. However, I do not wish to inherit from QToolBar and implement it myself. One of the things I desire and must have the most is the behavior of QToolButton (or QWidget) added to this custom ToolBar. I wish to have that shadowed-shaded effect on the Icon on mousePress. So I am very curious, how does the QToolbutton need to be styled for it to behave so? Or what to do to a QLabel showing an image for it to be shaded on mousePress?

Comment: OK, I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: Thank you. So far I figured a solution but I think  I'm reinventing the wheel -> Create QImage w/ same size icon, Type ARGB32. Create a QColor. Scan icon on x axis and y axis, set QColor to each pixel's color. Make the color darker by 200 via QColor's darker member function. On the same cooardinates of the private QImage, set this color and save it in the memory. On mousePress, replace the QLabel's Pixmap from Image with this one, revert to original desired Icon on mouseRelease. And this works as desired but I still think there should be a "one liner" to make QToolButton behave same way.